# How to remove grouping toolbar in Netbeans Platform

Tags: netbeans-platform

[image: remove this toolbar]

How to remove the toolbar above in a TopComponent (shown in Editor) on netbeans platform.
I tried turning off the checkboxes in Branding->Windows but still the toolbar above appears...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That component is the tab switcher and is part of the `org.netbeans.swing.tabcontrol.plaf.BasicScrollingTabDisplayerUI`.

It is an integrated part of the component and cannot easily be removed. Your only option is to [replace the entire TabDisplayerUI](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/farewell_to_space_consuming_weird).

If you require the tabs but not the tab switcher you could extend `BasicScrollingTabDisplayerUI` and override the method that creates the tab switcher. Then you could register this class as the TabDisplayerUI:

```
UIManager.put(
    TabDisplayer.EDITOR_TAB_DISPLAYER_UI_CLASS_ID, 
    "com.example.MyTabDisplayerUI");
```

Your module will need a dependency on the Tab Control module. See the link above for a complete description.